# Terraform and AWS: No Configuration Files Found Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am writing a small script that takes a small file from my local machine and puts it into an AWS S3 bucket.

My `terraform.tf`:

```hcl
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  version = "~> 1.6"
}
    
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket     = "${var.bucket_testing}"
    kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:12345678900:key/12312313ed-34sd-6sfa-90cvs-1234asdfasd"
    key     = "testexport/exportFile.tfstate"
    region  = "us-east-1"
    encrypt = true
  }
}
    
data "aws_s3_bucket" "pr-ip" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_testing}"
}
    
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "put_file" {
  bucket = "${data.aws_s3_bucket.pr-ip.id}"
  key    = "${var.file_path}/${var.file_name}"
  source = "src/Datafile.txt"
  etag = "${md5(file("src/Datafile.txt"))}"
    
  kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:12345678900:key/12312313ed-34sd-6sfa-90cvs-1234asdfasd"
  server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"
}
```

However, when I `init`:

```sh
terraform init

#=>

Terraform initialized in an empty directory!
    
The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
```

and then try to `apply`:

```sh
terraform apply

#=>

Error: No configuration files found!
    
Apply requires configuration to be present. Applying without a configuration would mark everything for destruction, which is normally not what is desired. If you would like to destroy everything, please run 'terraform destroy' instead which does not require any configuration files.
```

I get the error above.  Also, I have setup my default AWS Access Key ID and value.

What can I do?

Comment: If you're executing `terraform apply` from within a shell script, make sure that shell script doesn't cd into a different directory before the `terraform apply` command is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one comes across this now, I ran into an issue where my `TF_WORSPACE` env var was set to a different workspace than the directory I was in. Double check your workspace with

`terraform workspace show`

to show your available workspaces

`terraform workspace list`

to use one of the listed workspaces:

`terraform workspace select <workspace name>`

If the `TF_WORKSPACE` env var is set when you try to use `terraform workspace select` TF will print a message telling you of the potential issue:

```
The selected workspace is currently overridden using the TF_WORKSPACE
environment variable.

To select a new workspace, either update this environment variable or unset
it and then run this command again.
```

Answer (score 64):

This error means that you have run the command in the wrong place. You have to be in the directory that contains your configuration files, so before running `init` or `apply` you have to `cd` to your Terraform project folder.

Comment: thats what I did .. so my .tf files are in a folder project1 .. so I cd project1 and then run terraform init and then did the terraform plan

Comment: Can you do `ls -la` in this folder and post the results here? Also try `pwd` to list the current directory.

Comment: Looks like there was some issue with the vpn connectivity and was not able to connect to aws system .. it is working now after making some changes.

Answer (score 4):

```
Error: No configuration files found!
```

The above error arises when you are not present in the folder, which contains your configuration file.
To remediate the situation you can create a **.tf** in your project folder you will be working.
**Note** - An empty **.tf** will also eliminate the error, but will be of limited use as it does not contain provider info.
See the example below:-

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east" #Below value will be asked when the terraform apply command is executed if not provided here
   }
```

So, In order for the successful execution of the **terraform apply** command you need to make sure the below points:-

1. You need to be present in your terraform project folder (Can be any directory).
2. Must contain **.tf** preferably should contain terraform provider info.
3. Execute **terraform init** to initialize the backend & provider plugin.
4. you are now good to execute **terraform apply** (without any no config error)

Comment: But what if you ARE in the folder and you still get this message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error  emulated  by you, In my case it was not a VPN  error  but incorrect file
 system naming. I was in the project folder.To remedy the situation, i created a   .tf file
 with vim editor with the command vi aws.tf, then populated the file with defined  variables.  Mine is working.

See my attached images

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, remember terraform filename should end with .tf as extension

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252834/2227743).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason could be if you are using modules where the URL is incorrect.

When I had:

```hcl
source = "git::ssh://git@git.companyname.com/observability.git//modules/ec2?ref=v2.0.0"
```

instead of:

```hcl
source = "git::ssh://git@git.companyname.com/observability.git//terraform/modules/ec2?ref=v2.0.0"
```

I was seeing the same error message as you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error this morning when deploying to production, on a project which has been around for years and nothing had changed. We finally traced it down to the person who created the production deploy ticket had pasted this command into an email using Outlook:
terraform init --reconfigure

Microsoft, in its infinite wisdom, combined the two hyphens into one and the one hyphen wasn't even the standard ASCII hyphen character (I think it's called an "en-dash"):
terraform init –reconfigure

This caused Terraform 0.12.31 to give the helpful error message:

```
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
```

It took us half an hour and another pair of eyes to notice that the hyphens were incorrect and needed to be re-typed! (I think terraform thought "reconfigure" was the name of the directory we wanted to run the init in, which of course didn't exist. Perhaps terraform could be improved to name the directory it's looking in when it reports this error?)

Thanks Microsoft for always being helpful (not)!